# Convert contour (MatplotLib or OpenCV) to image of the same size as the original

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, matplotlib, contour

I have this contour obtained with MatplotLib:

[image: Contour]

Now, I want to use it as a normal Python image (PIL or array), because I want to apply it a mask (obtained with OpenCV).

The problem is that with MatplotLib, the image with the contour is resized, and a margin is added (for the axis, even if I don't draw the axis), so the image that I obtain from the figure of MatplotLib doesn't fit with the mask obtained with OpenCV.

I tried to get the same contour with OpenCV, but I don't obtain any result with the cv2.FindContours and cv2.DrawContours functions (if you know how to do it this way, please tell me... in this [previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586686/extract-external-contour-or-silhouette-of-image-python) you can see the original image and the contour that I want )

Another possible solution would be to convert the contour obtained with the MatplotLib to an image (PIL or array) with the same size as the original, and without margins.

I hope you could help me at least with one of these solutions!

--------------------------- EDIT ---------------------------

Rutger Kassies' answer is right. It wasn't working for me because I wrote this line...

```
ax = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frame_on=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])
```

... after using the contour function, and it must be before using the contour function. Keep that in mind!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I once posted the question how you could plot an image with .imshow and save it again so it would equal the input image. The respons i got might be helpfull in your case, this is how you can save the contour'ed image with the same dimensions:

```
from PIL import Image

im = np.array(Image.open('input_image.jpg').convert('L'))

xpixels = im.shape[1]
ypixels = im.shape[0]

dpi = 72
scalefactor = 1

xinch = xpixels * scalefactor / dpi
yinch = ypixels * scalefactor / dpi

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(xinch,yinch))

ax = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frame_on=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])

contour(im, levels=[240], colors='black', origin='image')

plt.savefig('same_size.png', dpi=dpi)
```

Comment: It would be better style to use the OO interface rather than the state machine interface.  ie  `c = ax.contour(...)` and `fig.savefig(...)`

Comment: I fully agree, the OO style is definitly better. This code was basically a modification of the code in the mentioned 'previous' post where i intended to stick as close to the original code.

Comment: @Rutger Kassies thanks for your answer. Please, see my edit in the question. I don't know why there is still a margin.

Comment: @Xithas, i cannot replicate your results. Mine overlap perfectly, maybe you initial figure has a different dpi or something? Perhaps try adding dpi=dpi when declaring it. See my results at: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/4190082/

Comment: @RutgerKassies your code is right. I used the `plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frame_on=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])` line after the contour function, and it must be before it. Thank you so much for your help!